# Should I add setters to properties even if I don't use the setter?

Tags: c#, properties

I've been trying to use properties more in C# as opposed to getter and setter methods.

I first had the question if it was ok to change attributes from within the class using the field rather than the property, and from [Should I use a Field or Property within the class to set values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863866/should-i-use-a-field-or-property-within-the-class-to-set-values), it seems that it is ok to do that (unless I read the answers incorrectly).

So if I didn't need to change the value of an attribute from outside the class, that means I may not need a setter for that property. Which comes to this question: I was wondering whether it is ok or not to make properties without a setter but with a getter (and vice versa).

For example, would it be ok to have a property like this.

```cs
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

Rather than

```cs
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    private set
    {
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

If I was never going to use the setter?

I feel like I might get some response asking why I am not using auto properties like

```cs
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

And the answer is personal preference I guess? And maybe because it is then easier to add more code to the setter or getter if I need to in the future.

Thinking about it now after writing the question, it seems like a bit of a silly question because clearly it should be ok to omit code that you aren't going to use. But just in case it's not ok, and just so I am sure, I have posted this question up.

Comment: Oops, I messed up the formatting. It won't let me edit it at the moment because there are too many edits happening, so it would be cool if someone else did it for me because I have to go for a few hours.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you. As for your question, it isn't clear what your concern is. If you don't need to expose a setter, don't expose a setter. And as far as automatic vs manual properties go, if you have the time to be writing out manual properties instead of automatic properties, you probably aren't accomplishing much in your projects. Use the tools you have to write succinct, clear code and don't waste your (and others') time writing and (more importantly) reading through large amounts of unimportant code. Manual properties should only be used when they are required.

Comment: Only use/add what you need now. No need for a Setter then leave it away. "And maybe because it is then easier to add more code to the setter or getter if I need to in the future." I disagree. Having the code full of things that might be needed in the future just blurs what it should and can do currently,

Comment: You shouldn't if you are certainly sure that you won't need to modify the value of the property in the future.

Comment: I would say don't expose setters if nothing needs them. However, never have set-only properties (with no getter), that would be perverse (not what you're asking of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to create properties without setters. A rule of thumb is to expose as little as possible a class, it is usually easier to add things than to remove things.

> And the answer is personal preference I guess? And maybe because it is then easier to add more code to the setter or getter if I need to in the future.

Since auto-properties are significantly shorter, I would argue that they are easier to read and understand. And therefore objectively better. There are refactoring tools available that can change your properties from one syntax to another.

If you want to keep the backing field I would consider the expression syntax to help reduce boiler plate:

```
public string Name => _name;
```

However, my absolute preference is to make objects immutable whenever possible, and just remove the setter:

```
public string Name {get;}
```

See also [Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) that add some additional syntactic sugar for working with immutable types.

Comment: Thanks for this. From your post and the other comments I've gathered that I should use auto-properties whenever possible because it makes it easier for me and others to read. I think I was just making excuses for myself to not wanting to change my coding practices, but this has made it clear that I should change that!